# Protection again self-assignment

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I was reading about copy-control and came across the following sample in the book *C++ Primer* (chapter 13.4).

My question is about the `remove_from_Folders();` inside copy assignment operator:
    If we firstly do `remove_from_Folders();`, in the case of self assignment, doesn't its `folders.clear();` clear the data member of rhs and cause a failure?

> ```
> Message& Message::operator=(const Message &rhs)
> {
>  // handle self-assignment by removing pointers before inserting them
>  remove_from_Folders();  // update existing Folders
>  contents = rhs.contents; // copy message contents from rhs
>  folders = rhs.folders;  // copy Folder pointers from rhs
>  add_to_Folders(rhs);  // add this Message to those Folders
>  return *this;
> }
>
> // remove this Message from the corresponding Folders
> void Message::remove_from_Folders()
> {
>  for (auto f : folders) // for each pointer in folders
>      f->remMsg(this);  // remove this Message from that Folder
>  folders.clear();
> }
> ```

The class is defined as:

> ```
> class Message {
>  friend class Folder;
> public:
>  // folders is implicitly initialized to the empty set
>  explicit Message(const std::string &str = ""):
>  contents(str) { }
>  // copy control to manage pointers to this Message
>  Message(const Message&);  // copy constructor
>  Message& operator=(const Message&); // copy assignment
>  ~Message();  // destructor
>  // add/remove this Message from the specified Folder's set of messages
>  void save(Folder&);
>  void remove(Folder&);
> private:
>  std::string contents;  // actual message text
>  std::set<Folder*> folders; // Folders that have this Message
>  // utility functions used by copy constructor, assignment, and destructor
>  // add this Message to the Folders that point to the parameter
>  void add_to_Folders(const Message&);
>  // remove this Message from every Folder in folders
>  void remove_from_Folders();
> };
> ```

Comment: Yes, it appears that the assignment operator will do just what you say in the event of a self-assignment.  Looks like a bug to me, the source comment notwithstanding.

Comment: The easy way; create a temporary copy and swap (which is exception safe, also)

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for [copy and swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: I'm reading the same book and just got to the copy control chapter.
I was asking myself the same question.. so it's a error isn't it?

Comment: I'm reading the chapter currently and immediately started to search for this. The issue was introduced in the first place during the *second print* of the book and is explained in the errata. From my point of view they have broken the code and not fixed it: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321714114/errata/9780321714114_errata_10-31-12.html

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Mooophy/Cpp-Primer/tree/master/ch13

the sampe code listed above is more appropriate for handling operator=(self)

```
Message& Message::operator=(const Message &rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) { // self-assigment check is necessary
                        // while remove_from_Folders() do folders.clear()
        remove_from_Folders();    // update existing Folders
        contents = rhs.contents;  // copy message contents from rhs
        folders = rhs.folders;    // copy Folder pointers from rhs
        add_to_Folders(rhs);      // add this Message to those Folders
    } 
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Can somebody explain why this answer was downvoted? It is short, self explanatory and adding only one line of code, if someone wants to keep *folders.clear()* in *remove_from_Folders()* this works and keep working even when further modifications to the class *Message* complicate the situation.